# Lost 120 pts. 3 Users Removed Same Day

Tags: support

Three users were removed on May 7 (it looks to me like they were all removed on the same day) this seems very odd to me and raises some red flags about whether I want to continue to use this site. Can I get the user names of these people who were removed?  I mean you could tell me this was housekeeping day and a lot of old accounts were removed on this day, but I have no way to determine if that is true or not.

If I am interpreting the explanation of User Removed given by this site, then 3 people on this same day requested that their accounts be deleted, or 3 on the same day were found to be in violation of site rules. Or this could be one person with more than one User name.

Answer (score 7):

This was due to violations of our rules in which several different accounts were involved. The violations happened across several communities.

Please understand that we will not discuss publicly who these users were, what they did exactly, or how we found out about it.

If it helps anything, I lost 1,205 reputation on Philosophy.SE that day. Don't worry, reputation is just a number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When a User is removed for violating Site policy, then points come off. So I have had, for instance, 120 points come off.  But I wonder, if such a User is readmitted, do the points come back?   The points should NOT come back for the reason that they were already found to be a trouble causer in the past. I don't want their points back if they are readmitted, because they are likely to cause trouble again and the points will just come off again when they are thrown off (again).

Comment: @Gordon The points are only removed in cases where the users are permanently removed, so this case is definitely settled for good.

Comment: I lost 2000 on the same day. An unwelcome surprise but rules are rules ...